# Problem with form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am facing a problem. I am having a form. Its action is ac.php. I want to change the action to sit.php.

For this what i did

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("digForm").innerHTML="<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='product_addtocart_form' method='post' action='http://localhost/bracelatest2/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9icmFjZWxhdGVzdDIvaW5kZXgucGhwL2JsYWNrLWJyYWNlLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/203/'>";
   </script>

<div id="digForm">
    <form action="ac.php">
</div>
```

Now I am using ajax and changing the inner html of `div myform` by

```
    <form action="sit.php">
```

But when i hit submit form is going to ac.php not to sit.php.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change the attribute then use

```
document.getElementById('myform').action = 'sit.php';
```

Check the demo here Shalu http://jsfiddle.net/bR2KA/

Answer (score 2):

Try from

```
    <div id="myform">
    <form action="ac.php">
```

to

```
<div>
<form action="ac.php" id="myForm">
```

then use jquery to change the action of the form by doing smth like

```
$("#myForm").attr('action', 'sit.php');
```

**edit**

if you include jQuery library in you're header like this:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myForm").attr('action', 'sit.php');
</script>
```

Comment: Is it not possible with javascript because I am not familiar with JQuery.Thanks for reply

Comment: include jQuery library in you're html header , then you'll be able to use the exact line "$("#myForm").attr('action', 'sit.php');" in you're js code when you whant to change the form action . nothing else required but to provide the form with the id="myForm"